# Monaco Editor - customize the folding icon (arrow-up and arrow-down) for a plus and minus

Tags: monaco-editor

Im playing with customizing Monaco Editor and I would like to change the folding icons (arrow-up and arrow-down). Is that something that can be customized ?

The examples for rendering glyphs does not seem to be what Im looking for https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-rendering-glyphs-in-the-margin

Neither the examples for exposed colors https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-exposed-colors

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following CSS to override the default folding icons with a `+` and `-`:

```
.codicon-folding-expanded:before {
    content: '\2212'; // Minus icon
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.codicon-folding-collapsed:before {
    content: '\002B'; // Plus icon
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

If you paste the above CSS snippet in the CSS tab in [this Monaco Playground example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-rendering-glyphs-in-the-margin) it will change the icons.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
!important
```

after content to get Ian A's answer to work.
Changed it a bit for a more Visual Studio like look:

```css
.codicon-folding-collapsed:before {
    content: '\002b' !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #676767;
    height: 11px;
    line-height: 6px;
}

.codicon-folding-expanded:before {
    content: '\2212' !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #676767;
    height: 11px;
    line-height: 6px;
}
```